# ThreadStatic field VS method parameter VS one instance per thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadstatic

Im working on a multithreaded application, therefore, I was always trying not to use private fields that may raise a conflict in the type instance i was using in different threads. Instead, I have been hauling information i needed to work as method parameters. This led to dozens of methods that all declared the same parameters:

```
private void MySubmethod(MyConfiguration configuration)
```

Now i was thinking to redesign the type and creating one instance per thread working, but then i stumbled upon the ThreadStatic attribute.

Is it a good idea to just declare a private threadstatic field, initialize it inside the main method each thread is calling and reuse this field inside all sub-methods, rendering the parameter obsolete? Or has it any drawbacks, so that i rather should concentrate on creating a new instance per Thread?

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static MyConfiguration _configuration;
```

Comment: It's very hard to tell that without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve. In *most* cases I'd avoid thread statics though.

Comment: Well, it thought that would be a rather general question, therefore i tried to stay generic... I may add that a single unit of work is completely done by a single thread, there is no "thread hopping" inside the execution of the existing main execution method.

Comment: If you use .NET 4.0 (or higher) I'd suggest using `ThreadLocal<T>` instead of `ThreadStaticAttribute` for less "magical stuff" ;-). @JonSkeet is of course right, very hard to give advice without more context - I second his advice to avoid thread-local fields as much as possible and work on the bigger picture to support parallelization better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to just declare a private threadstatic field, initialize it inside the main method each thread is calling and reuse this field inside all sub-methods, rendering the parameter obsolete?

No, it is not; it means that any code that touches threads is now deeply unreliable; and with things like `ThreadPool`, the TPL and `async`/`await`, threads are inevitable in modern applications (even if they are implicit rather than explicit in your code). Variables that are thread-dependent are also hugely problematic to debug. Unless there is a **very** good reason, my advice would be to retain the over-arching context, or plug into an existing robust implementation. For example, in a web application you might reasonably access the current request via the static methods - but even that you need to be careful to know whether you are on the *request* thread, vs on a worker thread that should have had everything it needed to know handed to it on a plate.

Comment: I'd also add that passing in the data required by your method makes your code more test-able. It lowers coupling and dependency and allows units of test to be created. The more state dependency across your application the less maintainable it will be